# Metrizable cellular topological spaces

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, textbook-recommendation

For a CW-complex, locally compact, metrizable, first countable and locally finite are equivalent conditions. A proof is available in https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4524/1/4524.pdf. I need the same result for cellular topological spaces, i.e. cellular objects of the Quillen model structure of spaces. It is possible to adapt the arguments of the Fritsch and Piccinini paper but I thought that someone wrote down the proof somewhere that I could cite.

> Any bibliographical reference for cellular spaces ? And by the way, is
> there any textbook expounding the proof for CW-complexes ? This fact
> is not in Hatcher's book "Algebraic Topology", not in Kozlov's book
> "Combinatorial Algebraic Topology" and not in Rotman's book "An
> introduction to Algebraic Topology". I am a bit surprised.

**Def**: A *cellular topological space* is a space $X$ such that the map $\varnothing\to X$ is a transfinite composition of pushouts of the generating cofibrations $\mathbf{S}^{n-1}\subset \mathbf{D}^n$ for $n\geq 0$.

Comment: What would be your reference for a text about this model structure of spaces?

Comment: The theorem (for CW complexes) is given in Fritsch and Piccinini's book *Cellular Structures in Topology* (see Proposition 1.5.17, for instance). It also appears in tom Dieck's books (for simplicial complexes). Could you be more specific about what you accept as a 'cellular object'?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე A reference about the Quillen model structure of spaces ? Mark Hovey's book for example.

Comment: @Tyrone  I edit the question. Your book is there https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4493/1/4493.pdf.